# Sample application with multitenant database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, azure, multi-tenant

I am trying to build a sample multi-tenant application targeting 100 tenants , Can i please know are their any good multi-tenant sample database which includes design, schema and sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Enzo SQL Shard](http://enzosqlshard.codeplex.com/) open-source framework which comes with a sample application. This framework comes with different sharding strategies; the one you may want to implement is the Compressed Shard. There is also documentation available showing you how this works.

Answer (score 0):

We at [Citus](http://www.citusdata.com) are building a distributed/sharded multi-tenant database using PostgreSQL. Our documentation includes a [use-case guide](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v6.2/use_case_guide/multi_tenant.html), which goes over an example application, and walks through sharding, and other multi-tenant specific features.